# Signed Apk gives error: com.b.a.a.d.a: Could not find method: setSoTimeout

Tags: android

I have app, when i installed it via Android Studio (Debug mode)  its working perfect in emulator and devices. but when i try to install signed apk in emulator or devices its installed successfully but when app opens it gives error. I commented all code which has httpconnection call and generate signed apk but error still exists.

I think error is in proguard file, how can i solve it.

i added below code in proguard but its not working...

**

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in F:\ADT\sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html
# Add any project specific keep options here:
# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-dontwarn com.viewpagerindicator.**
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.android.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.android.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.android.okhttp.**
```

**

**ERROR::**

```
02-22 15:30:23.571 4257-4287/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xeec35860, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err: com.b.a.a.d.a: Could not find method: setSoTimeout
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4280/? W/System.err: com.b.a.a.d.a: Could not find method: setSoTimeout
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.a.d.b.a(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.a.d.b.a(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.a.c.b.setOption(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:545)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:151)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.aa.run(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4280/? W/System.err: com.b.a.a.d.b.a(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.769 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.a.d.b.a(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.a.c.b.setOption(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:545)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:151)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.m.run(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-22 15:30:23.770 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: getsockname failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.getSocketLocalAddress(IoBridge.java:633)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.cacheLocalAddress(Socket.java:1001)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.m.run(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: getsockname failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.getsockname(Native Method)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getsockname(ForwardingOs.java:87)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.getSocketLocalAddress(IoBridge.java:629)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:    ... 17 more
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: getsockname failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.getSocketLocalAddress(IoBridge.java:633)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.cacheLocalAddress(Socket.java:1001)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.m.run(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-22 15:30:23.777 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-22 15:30:23.778 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-22 15:30:23.778 4257-4280/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: getsockname failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
02-22 15:30:23.778 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.getsockname(Native Method)
02-22 15:30:23.778 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getsockname(ForwardingOs.java:87)
02-22 15:30:23.778 4257-4280/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.getSocketLocalAddress(IoBridge.java:629)
02-22 15:30:23.778 4257-4280/? W/System.err:    ... 17 more
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: getsockname failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.getSocketLocalAddress(IoBridge.java:633)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.cacheLocalAddress(Socket.java:1001)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.aa.run(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: getsockname failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.getsockname(Native Method)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getsockname(ForwardingOs.java:87)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.getSocketLocalAddress(IoBridge.java:629)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:    ... 15 more
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: getsockname failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.getSocketLocalAddress(IoBridge.java:633)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.cacheLocalAddress(Socket.java:1001)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.ae.a(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at com.b.a.aa.run(Unknown Source)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: getsockname failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.getsockname(Native Method)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getsockname(ForwardingOs.java:87)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.getSocketLocalAddress(IoBridge.java:629)
02-22 15:30:23.781 4257-4279/? W/System.err:    ... 15 more
02-22 15:30:26.527 4257-4287/com.zeus.indiahistory W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-22 15:30:26.527 4257-4287/com.zeus.indiahistory W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xeec358e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

*

Comment: Have you configured ProGuard? Maybe you have to add an exception?

Comment: yes i have configured ProGuard, which exception i need to add and how ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Im getting it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to setting up proguard. You need to either disable proguard or add exceptions to proguard file. Add the below snippet to proguard file and test

```
-keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.net.http.**
```

Comment: default HttpURLConnection. but its working in debug mode. when i configured proguard and generate signed apk its not working...

Comment: Can you share the proguard file you are using

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check now

Comment: i changed proguard as per your edited answer, but not working same error